# I want to move from jquery Ajax to native Javascript Ajax . Here is my jquery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var ajax, ajaxHandler;

ajax.getUsernotification = {
  setup: function(command, data) {
    //retrieving the default attributes defined in ajaxhandler 
    var attributes = ajaxHandler.defaultAttributes;
    //Setting the attribute according to requirement 
    attributes.url = 'index.php/request/' + command.toLowerCase();
    attributes.data = data;
    attributes.type = 'POST';
    attributes.success = this.success,
    attributes.error = (this.error) ? this.error : attributes.error,
    //send request function defined in ajaxHandler below where
    //we send updated attributes to perform ajax command
    ajaxHandler.sendRequest(attributes);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    //if success then here is my functionality to execute 
    Controllers.NotificationController.displayUserWebNotification(data);
  }
}

 //ajax Handler function through which I set default attribute and send request function defined to send request to server 
ajaxHandler = {
  defaultAttributes: {
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'index.php/request',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: null,
    error: function(data) {
      errorHandler.showError('An Error occurred while trying to retreive your requested data, Please try again...');
    },
    timeout: function() {
      errorHandler.showError('The request has been timed out, Please check your Internet connection and try again...');
    }
  },
  sendRequest: function(attributes) {
    //i perform here through jquery 
    $.ajax(attributes);
  }
```

And here is JavaScript code

I have changed the send request function where jQuery use and convert it JavaScript:

```
sendRequest: function(attributes) {
  var xmlhttp;

  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      attributes.success(attribute.data);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open(attributes.type, attributes.url, true);
  xmlhttp.send(attribute.data);
}
```

Its work fine in jQuery but it give error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of `403 (Forbidden)` in JavaScript. I am using ubuntu 14.1 and I wonder whether the error is database related or incorrect code .

Comment: its work fine in jQuery. what does it mean?

Comment: its mean its give correct result and doesn't show any error.but in JavaScript it doesn't work .

Comment: `[...]I wounder whether the error is Database related or incorrect code .[...]` When the original code works, but not your implementation, then it is most likely because of incorrect code. Beside that you should check the networking tab and compare the request that is done by jQuery with the one you do. Is the url the same, are both sending the same parameters/data, is the method the same (you seem to use `POST` with jQuery wether `XMLHttpRequest` by default uses `GET`), ...

Comment: i set the method in attribute.type,then i passed the attribute.type in JS code .its tell the method when function is going to execute .